# Extend EntityManager methods

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

Currently, our resources are accessed based on static personas. An **Admin** can access a cluster (group of JPA) entities. An **Employee** can access other cluster of JPA entities. The list of JPA entities to persona mapping is available in our application. During the JPA events @PrePersist, @PreUpdate, @PreRemove and @PostLoad we check if the logged in user has the role necessary to perform this activity.

Now we want attribute based access control here. This means users with role **Admin1** can access only US employees and users with role Admin2 can access both US and EU employee details.

What I would like to achieve is to override a query

`Select * from MyTable` to be enhanced by 
`Select * from MyTable where (in clause)`

To make such changes across our application, will be an enormous activity. However, will it be possible to make such changes to the JPA query being generated with the security details?

Ours is a spring boot application using **Olingo OData 2** for all user interaction and not spring rest controllers. For OData queries, we also make use of query listener, that gives us the JPA query that can be enhanced using the **[ODataJPAQueryExtensionEntityListener](https://olingo.apache.org/javadoc/odata2/org/apache/olingo/odata2/jpa/processor/api/ODataJPAQueryExtensionEntityListener.html)**. However, queries generated during Asynchronous jobs and any other query not in the OData context. We want a uniform approach to enhance the queries from a central place.

Comment: I'm not sure the best or even all the options, but I'd suggest looking at Query redirectors (https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_queryredirectors.htm ) as one option. Others might be to try and leverage multittenant options in EclipseLink, as they are already able to modify queries on shared tables to use tenant specific filters ( https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/solutions/multitenancy002.htm ).

Comment: If you only have a few roles though, best option might be to create a new persistence unit for each, and allow you to optimize the same shared model using an orm.xml file to map/unmap relationships you don't want fetched or accessed, and set https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_additionalcriteria.htm or similar on the tables to ensure they are never accessing data they can't. Similar to Multitenant, but you've to handle writing to the filter columns yourself.

Comment: Hi Chris, 
I have been following up on the query redirectors. This looks promising. During my analysis over the last few days, I find that a select on an entity gives me the JPQL statement in the query redirector. However, if I navigate an association to another entity then I do not get the JPQL query. Instead I get the SQL statement using 

`databaseQuery.getTranslatedSQLString(session, arguments)`. Getting the JPQL would be preferred.

Comment: JPQL is an extra wrapper overtop of EclipseLink native expressions for JPA query support, and isn't something used for fetching mappings. Mappings build the queries using the native expression framework, so you are out of luck, sorry.